# Why does Ubuntu seem to be destroying my SSDs?

Tags: ssd, fsck, data-corruption

**Hi folks,**

I tried to upgrade from (Lubuntu) 18.04 to 19.04 over the weekend.

The upgrade didn't go as planned - the system wouldn't boot - so I decided to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.04 (I figured that as Lubuntu is no longer supporting LXDE, which was my main reason for using it, that it's time I found another distro).

I spent a day installing my programs only to begin seeing the dreaded busybox/intrafms messages at boot.

This happened with my previous SSD, although as I started running fsck on the live system when it began happening, this was probably the explanation. Eventually, even that stopped working, but as running fsck manually at every second boot wasn't a solution for me, I decided to buy a new disk.

In this case and the previous one, the SSDs started malfunctioning within a year. I don't dual boot, use the default swap setup, and don't generally forcibly turn the machine off. And I know for certain that I've been careful never to run fsck on the live system this time.

What gives?

Does Ubuntu simply fry SSDs?

Could I be getting lightning damage (there are only very occasional storms where I live, but the machine isn't on a surge protector)?

I never had this problem on my old (HDD) desktop or laptops.

TIA for anybody with thoughts to offer!

Comment: You probably need a firmware update on the SSD. Do `sudo lshw -C disk` and get the firmware version. Then go to the manufacturor's web site and look for updates. Report back.

Comment: What are the mount parameters? In particular any "something-atime" ones? Normally you should be using "relatime" or "noatime" (otherwise the SSD is writtentto to update file access time on every file open...), but these are the default these days.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses! I was asking because I had seen a couple of other comments here implying that Ubuntu and SSDs were known to have "issues" working together - and, as mentioned, I never experienced this problem before switching from HDD. The SSD I have installed is the Kingston SUV400S. I'm not sure whether it's a good brand or not - or even whether it was expensive - it was just what my local computer shop recommended.

Comment: (Just putting this here while I try find the firmware - and how to install it. This is new to me!)

description: ATA Disk
       product: KINGSTON SUV400S
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 37R5
       serial: 50026B7774033DC8
       size: 223GiB (240GB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=cc3e3c9b-696d-4b58-8032-cf45fba04a96 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096

Comment: This only seems to work in Windows. https://www.kingston.com/us/support/technical/ssdmanager Not sure if they have a version somewhere for Linux.

Comment: Does SSD firmware need to be periodically updated? And I'm a bit confused. I thought that fsck could only cause "damage" to the filesystem if the hardware was already damaged in the first place. Assuming that is not the case, why - every time that I run one fsck - does it spell the end for the hard drive with it eventually failing?
https://serverfault.com/questions/786648/when-is-fsck-dangerous

Comment: @oldfred - this looks like it might potentially be of use, although I'm not sure whether my particular model is "Sandforce based", whether the underlying firmware is up to date (I notice the repo was last updated last year) or even how to go about using the tool.
https://github.com/vinibali/kingston_fw_updater

Comment: 40 bad sectors being reported in 'Disks'. Can't install other packages because dpkg is reporting a fatal error. Think this disk is on the way out!